# Proof of formula for functions of matrices using Jordan cannonical form

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-explanation, matrix-decomposition, jordan-normal-form

I am having trouble comprehending the proof for Theorem 11.1.1 (p.557) in *Matrix Computations* by Golub and Van Loan. The theorem is that after "reducing" a square matrix $A$ into Jordan canonical form the function $f$ acting on the Jordan block $J_i$ is given by:
$$f(J_i)=\begin{pmatrix}
f(\lambda_i) & f^{1}(\lambda_i) & ... & \frac{f^{(m_i-1)}(\lambda_i)}{(m_i-1)!}\\
0 & f(\lambda_i)&...&...\\
...&...&...&f^{(1)}(\lambda_i)\\
0 $ ... & ... & ...& f(\lambda_i)
\end{pmatrix}$$

This is a result that I've seen to be given as a definition in *Functions of Matrices* by Higham, and the proof in Golub and Van Loan introduces matrix $G$ such that $$G=\lambda I+E$$ where $$E=(\delta_{i,j-1})$$ which I can only assume is a different version of the Kronocker delta. I am leaving a screenshot of the proof in the book [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HsCVs.png). If anybody could help me understand this proof or give another one I would be grateful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suspect that the confusing part of the proof is the invocation of Cauchy's integral theorem. I wouldn't worry about that; the only reason this is invoked is to say that a function $f$ can be substituted with its Taylor series, namely
$$
f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(k)}(\lambda)}{k!} x^k.
$$ 
If you're willing to take this as given, then the proof is straightforward.

Comment: Thanks @BenGrossmann, this was helpful.